# Multi-site manager, EE 4: where / how much?

Tags: multi-site-manager

I haven't used EE since version 2, and am looking to integrate it with a current project, using the MSM to control several subdomains. I'm almost embarrassed to ask this question because this is so ridiculous, but where am I supposed to purchase/download MSM from??! I'm reading [the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/msm/additional_sites.html):

> Pull up the manage purchases page in your account on EllisLab.com.
>   (Make sure you’re logged into the same EllisLab account used to
>   purchase the Multiple Site Manager license.) Next to the MSM license
>   in question, you’ll see the option to Add Sites. Follow the checkout
>   process in the store.

Well, I'm logged into my Ellislab account, I can see my prior purchases, and I can see "[the store](https://expressionengine.com/storehttps://expressionengine.com/store)", and there is not a whiff nor a hint of where to purchase a new copy of MSM.

Nor is it listed on Devot:ee. Nor does Google provide any relevant results. Nor does a search of their site provide any clues.

Goodness me, I'd sure love to give Ellislab some dollars... if only they'd tell me how many they'd like and where I deposit them. Help me out, someone.

Answer (score 0):

When you're log in.. in your purchase you see your license... There you can Add Site to your existing licenses. When you Add a site you can download only the license, upload it in the server and that's it! You don't really buy a MSM license. You just add a site to an existing license.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now since writing this that MSM is bundled as part of the EE4 package ($299)... but you only get one site. Each additional site is $199.

I can find absolutely nowhere in the docs, or anywhere, where this is explicitly stated so I hope this helps someone.

Also, when I first purchased EE 2.10 and MSM, it cost 299 and 199 respectively ($498), and you got 3 sites for that. Now they are wanting a grand total of $697 to run 3 websites with Expression Engine. That's too much in my book, so I am looking for other solutions.